# How to get the number formatter to work with automatic grammar agreement?

Tags: swift, foundation, formatter

I am having trouble getting the number formatter introduced in iOS 15+, macOS 12+ etc. to work with the automatic grammar agreement. The table below show examples of what I want to achieve.

| Locale Identifier | Output |
| --- | --- |
| en-GB | 1 book |
| en-GB | 5,000 books |
| de-DE | 1 book |
| de-DE | 5.000 books |

This works fine but no number formatting.

```
let count = 5_000
let output = AttributedString(localized: "^[\(count) \("book")](inflect: true)")

print(output) // 5000 books
```

I tried this and the automatic grammar agreement failed.

```
let count = 5_000.formatted()
let output = AttributedString(localized: "^[\(count) \("book")](inflect: true)")

print(output) // 5,000 book
```

I also tried this and it still failed.

```
let count = 5_000
let formatted = String(format: String(localized: "%@"), count.formatted())
let output = AttributedString(localized: "^[\(formatted) \("book")](inflect: true)")

print(output) // 5,000 book
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is better handled with localization. A “stringsdict”

Comment: Could you show me examples? I'm not actually interested in localisation. I just want to use the the built-in foundation code to manage it for me.

Comment: See [Localizing strings that contain plurals](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/localizing-strings-that-contain-plurals/) in the docs.

Comment: WWDC vídeos are your best resource, documentation can be found easily too. Just search “localization Apple developer” or “plurals Apple developer”. The “Developer” app is great and its search features have improved too.

Comment: Are you using this in a SwiftUI Text? SwiftUI Text has a default formatter built in that will work with AttributedStrings. Just printing to the console won't give you that formatting. So with SwiftUI Text your first code snippet should work.